# How to load variables from a text file?

Tags: batch-file

How to load variables from a text file?

This is my code that I use to save it:

```
@echo off
set name=john
set power=1000
set mana=100
set health=150
set name2=set name=%name%
set power2=set power=%power%
set mana2=set mana=%mana%
set health2=set health=%health%
(
echo %health2%
echo %mana2%
echo %power2%
echo %name2%
) > save.txt
pause>nul
```

Comment: You're basically saving a batch file with `set` commands, so just use `.bat` extension instead of `.txt` and call it directly: `call save.bat`.

Comment: ok thanks im new to advanced batch programming